# Request to merge my unregistered account with registered one, please

Tags: support

My unregistered account is https://serverfault.com/users/243018/johnz.

My registered account is https://serverfault.com/users/243033/johnz.

It would be really beneficial if the unregistered one could be merged into the registered one.  This would be a real help for

- helping me to track a prexisting discussion
- getting me to springboard some further answers forthcoming
- staying related

Is it possible to merge?

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately moderators are no longer able to merge accounts.

See the Help Center article: [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts)

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, visit the [contact form](https://serverfault.com/contact) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, [go here](https://serverfault.com/users/account-recovery) and enter the email address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

Comment: Thanks for your clear advice Michael.  I followed your steps and filled out the form.  Then I replied to two emails: one for each account which I had created.  I received a statement saying that the unregistered one would be removed and my unregistered answer transferred.  But at this moment, over 13 hours later, no change has actually occurred: the previous question is still attributed to my unregistered user.  Does the change take a long time to go through?

Comment: It worked!  My threads all now show up in the same registered account just fine. --- My apologies for bugging you earlier: problem resolved.