# Request to remove inadvertly account so that original serverfault account is preserved

Tags: support

Sorry about this.  I don't know how it happened.

I intended to login to my usual serverfault account.

```
 https://serverfault.com/users/243018/johnz
```

I logged in with stack exchange id (which is my gmail account and server fault password).

As a result I seem to have inadvently created a new serverfault account ...

```
 https://serverfault.com/users/251018/johnz
```

UPSHOT ---

- I do not need to keep the new 251018 account.  Can it safely be deleted?
- I should like my stackoverflow account (https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403571/johnz) to go back to display https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403571/johnz and https://serverfault.com/users/243018/johnz.  This is so that I can keep track.
- I wish for https://stackoverflow.com/users/1403571/johnz to no longer linking to https://serverfault.com/users/251018/johnz which was created by mistake

Apologies for the mix up.

Answer (score 6):

Not entirely sure what happened there - your accounts were merged, but your profiles were not.

I blame squirrels.

I've merged your *profiles*, and you should now be good to go.

Comment: Those dang squirrels!

Comment: ... with their long tails and stupid twitchy noses.

Comment: [He used the merge accounts tool.](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6605/126632) Maybe there's a bug lurking in it.

Comment: I think that's a pretty good bet, @MichaelHampton. Keeping my eyes open for more instances of this.

Answer (score 5):

Happily, we have an official [help-answer for this](https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts).

> If you have two accounts that you would like to join together, please sign into either account, [visit the contact form](https://serverfault.com/help/merging-accounts) and select ‘I need to merge user profiles’. After you contact us, the Stack Exchange Team will reach out to verify that you own both accounts. If we can confirm your ownership, we will initiate a merge.
>
> If you can't remember how to log in, go here and enter the email address you used to create the account you are trying to sign into.

Comment: [He's already done this once.](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6605/126632) I think something more is going on here.